# How to obtain the 95% confidence interval of accuracy of ROC ？

Tags: r, roc

I had obtained the AUC value and the 95% confidence interval through the pROC package, but I want to know how to obtain the 95% confidence interval of accuracy?

```
data(aSAH)
myroc <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)
myroc
ci.thresholds(myroc, thresholds = "best")
ci.auc(myroc)
```

result

```
Call:
roc.default(response = aSAH$outcome, predictor = aSAH$s100b)

Data: aSAH$s100b in 72 controls (aSAH$outcome Good) < 41 cases (aSAH$outcome Poor).
Area under the curve: 0.7314
> ci.thresholds(myroc, thresholds = "best")
95% CI (2000 stratified bootstrap replicates):
 thresholds sp.low sp.median sp.high se.low se.median se.high
      0.205 0.7083    0.8056  0.8889 0.4878    0.6341  0.7805
> ci.auc(myroc)
95% CI: 0.6301-0.8326 (DeLong)
```

Comment: At which threshold(s) do you want to calculate your accuracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify at which threshold you want to calculate your accuracy. I will show how to obtain it for the "best" threshold as you did for the sensitivity and specificity.

The pROC package has a `coords` which can calculate many different measures like accuracy. For instance you can do:

```
coords(myroc, x = "best", ret = "accuracy", transpose = FALSE)
```

You can obtain the confidence intervals of all these measures with the `ci.coords` function:

```
ci.coords(myroc, x = "best", ret = "accuracy", transpose = FALSE)
```